# SQLiteStudio import extremely slow

Tags: sqlite, sqlitestudio

SQLiteStudio is lightning fast with queries, but whenever I import a .csv of even modestly large size (say, 60,000 rows, smaller than 2MB), it takes 5 minutes or more to import. And somewhat larger files can run 15 minutes before I give up. The files appear clean, and this happens with others I know who use the program. Are we doing something wrong? Is there a way to speed this up?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug: https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/issues/3191
It's fixed for upcoming version 3.2.0. It's been optimized to import by over 1000 times faster.